# Do children learn to play musical instrument more easily than adults?

Tags: learning, music

People say that it is harder for adults to learn to play instrument, because *their muscle became stiff*. Is there evidence for this claim?

Comment: People? Can you provide a source for this claim? Additionally, what have you found in your initial research?

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, [most forms of learning become harder as one ages](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00817/full). Probably the most relevant aspect for your question is [learning fine motor skills](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11556-008-0030-9):

> most studies revealed that performance gains in fine motor tasks are diminished in older adults

Comment: I like it when the number of sources nearly exceeds the number of lines. +1 A simple approach to this question proving to be quite effective.